# How to create a page-break between two XSL templates

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to use `page-break` or any space between two templates.

```
<xsl:template match="content_name">
   <fo:block space-after="7pt" space-after.conditionality="retain" line- 
 height="1.147" font-family="Calibri" font-size="15pt" font-weight="bold" language="FR">
   </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<!--Here i want to add a page break-->

<xsl:template match="pro_list">
  <fo:block space-after="15pt" space-after.conditionality="retain" line-height="1.147" font-family="Calibri" font-size="15pt" font-weight="bold" text-decoration="underline" language="FR">
  </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

Could you please tell me how to achieve this?
I have tried many options, but none of them is working...

Comment: It is hard to understand what the question is. Can you give some examples ?

Comment: This is because there is nothing to do between templates. If you want something to be done, you need a template for it.

Comment: Content_name and Pro_list contains list of value. so before the list started i need a page break at the start. If i write page-break inside the block for every loop value it is doing page break.I just want Pro_list value should start from new_page. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

**You cannot do this.**
Your question is the result of a fundamental misunderstanding of how XSLT does work. Each `xsl:template` *matches* one specified form of XML. Trying to add a *match* between two templates is futile. So every `page-break` functionality has to be *in* a template and *not* between two templates.

Therefore you can add a `page-break` here

```
<xsl:template match="content_name">
   <fo:block space-after="7pt" space-after.conditionality="retain" line- 
 height="1.147" font-family="Calibri" font-size="15pt" font-weight="bold" language="FR">
   <!-- Add a page break here -->
   </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

or there

```
<xsl:template match="pro_list">
  <fo:block space-after="15pt" space-after.conditionality="retain" line-height="1.147" font-family="Calibri" font-size="15pt" font-weight="bold" text-decoration="underline" language="FR">
  </fo:block>
  <!-- Add a page break here -->
</xsl:template>
```

or in any other location *in* those two templates. But not *between* those templates!

Comment: Content_name and Pro_list contains list of value. so before the list started i need a page break at the start. If i write page-break inside the block for every loop value it is doing page break.I just want Pro_list value should start from new_page. How to start pro_list value from a new page??Thanks for your help

Comment: <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
  <xsl:template match="pro_list">
  <fo:block break-after="page"/>
   </xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>   I have written this in between two templates but it doesnot work